# Please welcome a new moderator: Erica

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm pleased to announce a brand new member of the [Parenting moderator team](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators):

[image: profile for Erica at Parenting Stack Exchange, Q&A for parents, grandparents, nannies and others with a parenting role]

What I appreciate the most about Erica is her reasoned approach to answering which is always backed by data, research, and logic as needed. These qualities are also very helpful for a moderator—especially on a site that covers a topic so often overrun by opinion, tradition, and presuppositions. Please join me in welcoming Erica to the team!

Answer (score 7):

Welcome, Erica!!! So glad you are a moderator!

Comment: I'd second anon's sentiment - welcome! I think you'll fit in perfectly. Don't be afraid to ask about any mod tools etc.

Comment: +1 far each of those exclamation points!

Answer (score 5):

Thank you Jon :) It was a surprise to be asked, but I'm honored and humbled and will do my best to continue contributing.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome Erica :-) Nice to hear that you promoted as moderatpr

Answer (score 4):

Welcome Erica! I was always a bit surprised to *not* see the Mod diamond when I see your name on comments or answers. Even though I've only been a member of the Parenting community for a short time, I think you'll serve us well. :)