# Stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I would like to announce I am stepping down as moderator. I am pleased that Erica [agreed](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/802/644) to take my place.  You may or may not have noticed her skill at defusing situations and educating new users while treating them with respect, but as a moderator I certainly noticed how much easier she made my job.  She was my first choice when Jon asked me to recommend a replacement.

I do intend to stick around.  This is a great community that I would like to see grow.  Truth be told, I'm a little burned out on *all* my social media at the moment, and need to cut back in a way that would leave me unable to give this site the attention it deserves from its moderators.  Also, moderators continually get their attention drawn to the negative visitors to the site, few though they may be, and it was starting to get to me.  I'm looking forward to being blissfully ignorant of the trolls and spammers again, with a new appreciation for the new moderators willing to take them on.

See you around!

Comment: :-(  Wishing you blissful ignorance and the rest and recreation you deserve. I know since I've been here, you've worked very hard. Please, though, don't be a stranger. Your wisdom is always welcome.

Comment: Karl, you're leaving hard shoes to fill :) Thank you for all the work and effort that you have put in.